# Finding the limit (if it has one) of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, trigonometry

I am trying to understand the limiting behaviour of the ratio $$\frac{|\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\sin(2\pi x^3/p)+\cos(2\pi x^3/p)|}{\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}|\sin(2\pi x^3/p)|+|\cos(2\pi x^3/p)|}$$
as $p\rightarrow \infty$ and $p$ is a prime (I am not sure if this condition makes a difference or not). I have done some computations with the first 1000 primes and I got the following[image]

It does seem likely that it has 0 as its limit, but I can not conclude that of course from this computation. My questions are

- Does this actually have a limit?
- If not, can we find a subsequence of the primes, such that this has a non-zero limit?

I want to know your thoughts and I hope you can suggest some ways to attack this problem.

Comment: the numerator is $0$ when i try the first few primes ?!!

Comment: @Ahmad I think you are right, for p=3 and p=5 it is indeed 0, but for p=7 it is approximately 4.74

Comment: Is it true that $\sum_{x=0}^{p-1}\sin(2\pi x/p)+\cos(2\pi x/p)=0$? If that is the case, then the numerator is always zero whenever the map $\mathbb{F}_p\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_p \colon x\mapsto x^3$ is surjective. I know that for $p=7$, this map is not surjective, but for $p=3$ and $p=5$ it is surjective.